# Pickle.load gives jax-related error, no matter what

Tags: python, json, package, pickle, jax

Good evening,
I will start by saying that I am a total newbie in coding, and although not strictly demanded in my job it would be a big bonus to have a better knowledge of it.
I am currently working on the conversion of a pickle file in JSON, and I did find some python scripts around the internet (which I am able to read, I think). However, I always encounter an error during the pickle.load command. This is an example script I took from the internet:

```
Pickle2JSON is a simple Python Command Line program for converting Pickle file to JSON file.
Arguments: Only one (1) argument is expected which is the pickle file.
Usage: python pickle2json.py myfile.pkl
Output: The output is a JSON file bearing the same filename containing the JSON document of the converted Pickle file.
# import libraries
import pickle
import json
import sys
import os
# open pickle file
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as infile:
    obj = pickle.load(infile)
# convert pickle object to json object
json_obj = json.loads(json.dumps(obj, default=str))
# write the json file
with open(
        os.path.splitext(sys.argv[1])[0] + '.json',
        'w',
        encoding='utf-8'
    ) as outfile:
    json.dump(json_obj, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Credits: [Git](https://gist.github.com/romgapuz/c7a4cedb85f090ac1b55383a58fa572c)

Whenever I run this or other similar scripts I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\geu19\Desktop\convert.py", line 16, in <module>
  obj = pickle.load(infile)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jax._src.device_array'
```

I already installed jax and jaxlib (both 0.4.13, while python in 3.11.2), already tried different versions, but to no avail. Can someone help? I have been totally stuck on this for days and maybe it's something silly I still don't understand.
Thanks.

I tried changing versions, both of python and jax packages.
I expected to have a JSON file, I got frustration and headaches.

Comment: How exactly was the pickle file produced? Where did you get it? What version of python was used?

Comment: You may have multiple python's installed and the one with jax is not the one used here. At the top of the file, try to import jax and then its subcomponents. First `import jax` then `import jax._src.device_array' as the first lines in the file. If this fails, there's your problem.

Comment: The pickle file comes from an Alphafold run I did some time ago. I don't know much how they are generated, but they store data which I would like to extract and work on. 
This is much of the information I got
"result_model_x.pkl: A pickle file containing a nested dictionary of the various NumPy arrays directly produced by the model. "

Also importing jax and subcomponents first in the script didn't work. So I should find  out which python version is using which jax version, I guess

Comment: My wild guess is that `jax._src.device_array` was present in an older version of jax which was used to create the pickle file, but that component was removed in your newer version of jax.

Comment: Perhaps you could find out exactly which version of jax was used, and install the matching version on your computer.

Comment: @JohnGordon your question about how the pickle file was produced did the trick!!! I actually remembered that we were given a list of packages and versions to install in our environment prior to using alphafold, and indeed I found the right version and now the script works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In general, `pickle` is only safe to use if you load the pickle file in the *exact same environment* in which you saved the file. This is because the serialization makes use of object details that may change across package versions or Python versions.

In this case, it looks like you saved the pickle file in a runtime with JAX version 0.3.X (when the JAX array type was `DeviceArray`) and are attempting to load it in a runtime with JAX version 0.4.X (where `DeviceArray` has been replaced with `jax.Array`; see [CHANGELOG](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#jax-0-4-1-dec-13-2022)).

You should be able to fix this by installing JAX version 0.3.25 or older. To avoid this kind of difficulty in the future, you may consider using a more stable array serialization approach such as [`jax.numpy.save`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.save.html), which uses the NumPy `.npy` file format.